# Batch file to increment last number of all filenames?

Tags: batch-file

This is my first post as I've always been able to find help from previous threads here.

My issue sounds simple but I am having a hard time with it and very much appreciate any help.

I am trying to write a batch to simply increment the last character of all drawing files, `.dwg`, in a folder. The number represents the revision of the drawing. The Revision order is an `A,0,1,2,3,4,...etc.` so I'm not sure if it is more difficult changing an `a` to a `0` as well as incrementing numbers.

I am using Windows 7 and all files are named in this manner:

> SAJ9495FA2006PLCE020140601-A
> needs to change to
> SAJ9495FA2006PLCE020140601-0
>
> SAH7830FA2006PLCE020110101-0
> needs to change to
> SAH7830FA2006PLCE020110101-1
>
> SA8096FA2006PLCE020104001-5
> needs to change to
> SA8096FA2006PLCE020104001-6

Thank you or any input and for your time.

Edit:

The code below works, however it removes the `-` from filename and I would like it stay. Also it copies the files to a processed folder and I'd prefer they stay as well. Not sure how to edit it any further...

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

mkdir processed
mkdir temp

set ext=dwg

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b *.!ext!') do (
    set file=%%~nA
    set name=!file:~0,-2!
    set /a num=!file:~-1!+1

    xcopy "%%A" "temp" > nul
    ren "temp\%%A" "!name!!num!.!ext!" > nul
    move "temp\!name!!num!.dwg" "processed" > nul
    Echo %%A -^> !name!!num!.!ext!
)
```

Comment: I wouldn't rule out `python` here. A simple script is all you need.

Comment: Provide material you have so far attempted.

Comment: tried this last time but wrote it wrong. It renames all files to 0 then 1 then 2 etc.  @echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cd "\currentdirectory where files are present"
set /a incr=0
FOR %%G in ("*.dwg") DO call :rename "%%G"


:rename
set file1=%~1 
set /a incr=!incr!+1
ren !file1! !incr!.dwg
endlocal

Comment: @echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
cd "\currentdirectory where files are present"
set /a incr=0
FOR %%G in ("*.dwg") DO call :rename "%%G"


:rename
set file1=%~1 
set /a incr=!incr!+1
ren !file1! !incr!.dwg
endlocal

Comment: googling python now.... I'm trying to keep this in notepad so other coworkers can use it without downloading something seperate but thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

mkdir processed
mkdir temp

set ext=dwg

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b *.!ext!') do (
set file=%%~nA
        set name=!file:~0,-2!
set /a num=!file:~-1!+1

xcopy "%%A" "temp" > nul
ren "temp\%%A" "!name!!num!.!ext!" > nul
move "temp\!name!!num!.dwg" "processed" > nul
Echo %%A -^> !name!!num!.!ext!
)

Comment: That code above works however it removes the "-" and puts the files in a proessed folder. Would prefer they just stay where they are and get overwritten

Comment: Could there happen to be multiple revisions of the same drawing?

Answer (score 1):

A solution preserving/reinserting the `-`

It uses a simple for iterating the matching files and a `for /f` to split the name at the `-`

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set ext=dwg
set A=-1
for %%A in (*-?.%ext%) do for /f "tokens=1,2delims=-" %%B in ("%%~nA") do (
    set /a num=%%C + 1
    Echo Ren "%%A" "%%B-!num!%%~xA"
    Rem  Ren "%%A" "%%B-!num!%%~xA"  > nul
)
```

Sample output:

```
Ren "SA8096FA2006PLCE020104001-5.dwg" "SA8096FA2006PLCE020104001-6.dwg"
Ren "SAJ9495FA2006PLCE020140601-A.dwg" "SAJ9495FA2006PLCE020140601-0.dwg"
Ren "SAH7830FA2006PLCE020110101-0.dwg" "SAH7830FA2006PLCE020110101-1.dwg"
```

If the output is OK remove the Rem in front of the Ren command.

Answer (score 1):

This task is not that trivial, because you have to consider some issues:

- the revision numbers might consist of more than a single digit;
- the file names might contain more than one hyphens (`-`);
- there might be multiple versions of the same base file available, so you need to increment the highest revision first in order to avoid conflicts with already existing file names;

So this is my approach, regarding all these things (see all the explanatory remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_ROOT=%~1"     & rem // (provide path to root directory as command line argument)
set "_MASK=*-*.dwg" & rem // (mask to find files to process)
set "_TMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (path to temporary file)

rem // Write list of files to rename to temporary file:
> "%_TMPF%" (
    rem // Loop through all matching files:
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D "%_ROOT%\%_MASK%"') do (
        rem // Store original file name:
        set "FILE=%%F"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem // Extract last `-`-separated part from file name:
        for %%I in ("!FILE:-=" "!") do set "LAST=%%~I"
        rem // Extract file name with the last `-`-separated part removed:
        set "REST=!FILE!|" & for %%J in ("!LAST!") do set "REST=!REST:-%%~J|=!"
        rem // Remove any leading zeros from the past part:
        for /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%E in ("!LAST!") do set "LAST=%%E"
        if not defined LAST set /A "LAST=0"
        rem // Increment last part:
        if /I "!LAST!"=="A" (set /A "NEXT=0") else set /A "NEXT=LAST+1"
        rem // Left-zero-pad incremented last part:
        set "NPAD=0000000000!NEXT!" & set "NPAD=!NPAD:~-10!"
        rem /* Return list with three items:
        rem     # file name without last part + `-` + zero-padded incremented last part;
        rem     # original file name;
        rem     # file name without last part + `-` + incremented last part (non-padded);
        rem    this is then needed for alphabetical sorting in descending order: */
        echo(!REST!-!NPAD!^|!FILE!^|!REST!-!NEXT!
        endlocal
    )
)

rem // Loop through sorted temporary file:
for /F "tokens=2* delims=| eol=|" %%G in ('sort /R "%_TMPF%"') do (
    rem // Actually rename a file:
    ECHO ren "%_ROOT%\%%G" "%%H"
)

rem // Clean up temporary file:
del "%_TMPF%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Remove the upper-case `ECHO` in front of the `ren` command to actually rename files.

Answer (score -1):

My Solution:

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set ext=dwg

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b *.!ext!') do (
    set file=%%~nA
    set name=!file:~0,-1!
    set /a num=!file:~-1!+1

    ren "%%A" "!name!!num!.!ext!" > nul
    Echo %%A -^> !name!!num!.!ext!
)
```

Comment: What if there is a 2-digit revision number?

Comment: The first example in your question shows an `A` is supposed to be changed to a `0`.